# MeeGo Security Platform and Libraries

Tags: security, meego

I want to know what cryptographic libs a MeeGo platform uses by default and what else it offers for security.

Can anybody explain/provide me with some links?

Thanks

Comment: aegis-crypto, openssl: http://wiki.meego.com/Security/Architecture